# Gray border when using NSBorderlessWindowMask

Tags: cocoa, macos

Whenever I try to create a custom window using NSBorderlessWindowMask and set an NSView (for example an NSImageView) as its contentView, I get a 1px gray border around the NSView and I don't seem to be able to get rid of it.

I have followed several approaches including Apple's RoundTransparentWindow sample code as well as several suggestions on StackOverflow.

I suspect the gray border is either coming from the window itself or the NSView.

Have any of you experienced this problem or do you have a possible solution?

The code is fairly straightforward. This is the init method of the custom window:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag {
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];

    if (self != nil) {
        [self setAlphaValue:1.0];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];     
        [self setOpaque:NO];
    }

    return self;
}
```

To test this, in IB I place an NSImageView in that custom window WITHOUT border and yet the image in the NSImageView has a border. The same goes for other NSView subclasses, such as NSTextField, NSTableView.

In addition, I also noticed that the same is happening with the sample application (RoundTransparentWindow) of Apple. Is it even possible to draw an NSView in a custom window without a 1px border?

Thanks

Comment: Joe -- It's definitely the NSView that has a border. Even if I use a simple NSTextField and I turn of the border, it still draws a border (1px gray) around the NSTextField. If I use a bordered NSTextField, then the NSTextField has a 2px border (1px + 1px). If I have multiple NSViews, then it draws a 1px border around each NSView.

Comment: Have you tried setting your imageview as a subview of the contentView?

Comment: Richard -- That's what I am currently doing so that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this happens when you use a regular NSView with no drawing? I bet not. Other controls (like NSImageView)have borders. Maybe you should double check to make sure they're turned off whe possible.

**Update** - How do you get your view into your window? You don't include that code. I created a basic test project ([download it here](http://media.nozzi.name/sharedexamples/BorderlessTransparentWindowTest.zip)) with an image well and it works just fine. See for yourself.

Comment: I am aware that NSImageView or NSTextField have borders by default, but I'm not talking about that border. Please, read my comment above in reply to Joe Blow.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do the trick. In fact, it is a necessary call since my window would otherwise not be transparent, which is the whole idea behind what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Joshua. I've looked at your test project, but there is also a 1px border around your image in your image view. It might look like an unimportant detail, but it can really screw up the UI.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're seeing. Can you post a screenshot? Something's not right here. Is the border you're seeing rectangular or does it outline the exact shape of the image? If you set the image to nothing in the xib, does the border remain?

Comment: ... also, if you build this example for release, put it somewhere reachable, then log into a separate user account and run it, does the border remain? I'm starting to suspect a third-party installed tool/theme-changer is involved here.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing against a white background: http://media.nozzi.name/sharedexamples/LookMaNoBorder.png Absolutely no 1-pixel border. Looks the same as the icon does in Preview.app.

Comment: It is a border outlining the image shape. Have a look at this screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1951780/testproject.png I have slight altered your project by adding a normal window with a normal NSImageView with the same image. You can see that the normal NSImageView has no (extra) 1px border, whereas the borderless window does have a thicker border.

Comment: I suppose my monitor could use calibrating. The borders look the same to me, so I used a plain white rectangle as the image and saw the border. How annoying. I tried turning off the shadow for the borderless window in IB and magically the border goes away. Perhaps you should do the same and handle shadow drawing yourself if you want it there.

Comment: I seem to recall an issue where I had to window shadow drawing off and then back on so that it would update.  HTH

Comment: Joshua and Richard -- Thanks for your help! I'm going to go with a window without a shadow and draw the shadow myself as this seems the best option at this point.