# Grey border around view when using NSBorderlessWindowMask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I'm having the exact same problem as in this question:

[Gray border when using NSBorderlessWindowMask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534396/gray-border-when-using-nsborderlesswindowmask)

However, the accepted answer (as in the comments) of removing the window shadow doesn't seem to work, at least on Lion.

---

I've subclassed `NSWindow`, and created a borderless window in this manner:

```
-(id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag {

    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect 
                            styleMask:(NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
                              backing:bufferingType 
                                defer:flag];

    [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
    [self setOpaque:NO];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [self setHasShadow:YES];

    [self setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel];
    return self;
}
```

Please note that this app will only be run on Lion (so `NSResizableWindowMask` doesn't change the appearance).  I tried disabling the shadow, and toggling numerous settings for my window but I can't seem to remove this grey border:

[image]

Nowhere in my code do I add a border.  I simply have a `NSSplitView` added in Interface Builder in a window.  During runtime I add the colored view as a subview to the left pane of the split view, completely filling the bounds of the left split view.

*Edit: This happens even using a simple `NSView`, not even a split view.*

---

`TL;DR`: Why does my `NSView` have a grey border around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok got it. to remove the shadow simply add this to your `NSWindow` subclass:

```
- (BOOL)hasShadow {
    return NO;
}
```

and to remove the border you need to know that this border is coming from the view - not the window (just like you said it in your edit). So you have to disable the border for the view with this code:

```
[myview setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!  Actually removing the shadow wasn't the problem, but I was trying that to see if it affected the little border thing.  Cheers!

Comment: @sudorm-rf What kind of class is `myview`?