# Unexpected border around a borderless NSWindow with custom graphics

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have an borderless subclass of `NSWindow` with custom graphics with rounded corners:

**MyCustomWindow**:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation 
{ 
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    if (self) {
        // Start with no transparency for all drawing into the window
        [self setAlphaValue:1.0];
        // Turn off opacity so that the parts of the window that are not drawn into are transparent.
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

**MyCustomView**:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    [[NSColor clearColor] set];
    NSRectFill([self frame]);
    [backgroundImage compositeToPoint:NSZeroPoint operation:NSCompositeSourceOver];
}
```

However, every once in a while (maybe 1 out of 10) when I start the application the graphics looks wrong because I get an grey one-pixel square border around the window. It is not set around my custom graphics but around the window's frame, which means that it negates my round corners.

Is there something I am missing in my subclasses?

**EDIT:**
Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Seems I had the same problem and I got it fixed. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124349/grey-border-around-view-when-using-nsborderlesswindowmask

Comment: Sorry Sam, I didn't. I ended up using a less customized design where the window edges were kept as standard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set background color to transparent color. Add this to Your *MyCustomWindow*:

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```

Your *MyCustomWindow* should look like this:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation 
{ 
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    if (self) {
        // Start with no transparency for all drawing into the window
        [self setAlphaValue:1.0];

        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

        // Turn off opacity so that the parts of the window that are not drawn into are transparent.
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Try edit Your drawRect:

Replace it with:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    NSBezierPath * path;
    path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect xRadius:6 yRadius:6];
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [path fill];

    /* If this example will help You. Replace redColor to clearColor and use this instead RectFill */
}
```

*Also add in Your *MyCustomWindow* [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]]; what I was said earlear.

Still with border?

It's working for me.

Comment: Hi Justin. Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately your suggestion did not solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm.. that should work. Maybe You can add screen shot in order to be more clearly to understand what's wrong.

Comment: I have now added an screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However, the problem still remains. Just to clarify, I don't have a problem with creating the round edges; In my case they came from the background image. My problem is that SOMETIMES the square border comes "uninvited". So what I am really trying to do is get rid of that unwanted border, which also comes using your solution.